# Sending files through email - multipart

Tags: html, forms, file, email, multipart

I want to make a HTML document that allows the user to send files through email. I've read I have to use the "multipart/form-data".

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>File test</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<FORM ACTION="mailto:user@mail.com" METHOD="POST" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">
Send a file
<BR><INPUT NAME="File" TYPE="file">
<BR><INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Send">
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

This is a simple example that I cannot fix. What am I missing?

Edit:
The problem is that I receive the email without any content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mailto: URI scheme, when used for form actions, requires a combination of a compatible browser and email client. These are not so common as to be practical for use on the WWW (see also [The Mythical Mailto:](http://isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html)).

I'm not aware of *any* combination that supports *file attachments* via that scheme.

You need to use an HTTP (or HTTPS) URI with a server side form handler.

Answer (score 0):

Mail will be sent successfully with your default mail client that is set-up in your machine. Make sure you have default mail client set-up. Eg: Outlook Express, Office Outlook.

Comment: I do have one. The problem is I receive the message without any content. Sorry I didn't make that clear. I'll add that information to the question.